# How to get other than "<no value>" when interpolating {{ .Environment.SOME_VAR }} (with SOME_VAR set) into cache key?

Tags: circleci-2.0

Using this configuration:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  test:
    docker:
    - image: nixorg/nix:circleci
    environment:
      NIXPKGS_REV: 3c83ad6ac13b67101cc3e2e07781963a010c1624
    steps:
    - restore_cache:
        name: Restore Nix Store Paths
        keys:
        - paymentserver-nix-store-v1-{{ .Environment.NIXPKGS_REV }}
        - paymentserver-nix-store-v1-
```

The job tries to restore the cache using the key `paymentserver-nix-store-v1-<no value>`.

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-job says this is the correct way to set an environment variable.  https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/#using-keys-and-templates says interpolating environment variables this way is supported for cache keys.

What's going on?  How do I use the value of an environment variable in a cache key?

Comment: I did refund your bounty as it should get back to you for the definitive answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closer reading of [the documentation about using environment variables in cache keys](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/#using-keys-and-templates) reveals the issue (emphasis mine):

> The environment variable variableName (supports any environment variable exported by CircleCI or added to a specific Context—**not any arbitrary environment variable**).

"exported by CircleCI" seems to mean the list of mostly-`CIRCLE_...`-prefixed variables (documented as "[Built-In Environment Variables](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#built-in-environment-variables)") while (unsupported) "any arbitrary environment variable" includes variables set in an `environment` section in `config.yml`.

I ended up working around this limitation something like this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: "nixorg/nix:circleci"

    environment:
      NIXPKGS_REV: "3c83ad6ac13b67101cc3e2e07781963a010c1624"

    steps:
      - "run":
          name: "Prepare For Cache Key"
          command: |
            echo "${NIXPKGS_REV}" > nixpkgs.rev

      - restore_cache:
          name: "Restore Nix Store Paths"
          keys:
            - paymentserver-nix-store-v1-{{ checksum "nixpkgs.rev" }}
            - paymentserver-nix-store-v1-
```

That is, instead of trying to use the value of `NIXPKGS_REV` from the environment in the cache key, an earlier step writes the value of that environment variable to a file and then the cache key is constructed using the checksum of that file.  Computing file checksums for use in cache keys is well supported so this produces a cache key which is derived from the value of the environment variable.  The key doesn't *contain* the value of the environment variable but since the key's only purpose is to be unique for certain unique inputs, using the checksum works just as well.